# Froala Editor JS/Rail Implementation Issues: Key not Seen and Code View Buggy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, froala

I'm attempting to make the Froala gem work in my Rails 5.2 app and am having two issues:

1. The license key is not being recognized, so when I look at my live site it has an "unlicensed editor" bar. (Picture shows angry red bar and scadzillions of JS errors.)
   [image]
2. The code editor button makes a second text box appear inside the first, rather than changing the original text to the code view.  This one only shows up on the live site (Heroku), but does not happen on `localhost`.  I suspect something could be amuck with the asset pipeline...?
   [image]

The editor is rendered like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@blog) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, id: "wysiwyg" %>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions text-center">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-outline-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have the following on-page initialization of my Froala instance:

```
<!-- script for FROALA-WYSIWYG -->
<script>
  $('#wysiwyg').froalaEditor({
    key: '<%= ENV['FROALA_ACTIVATION_KEY'] %>',
    inlineMode: false,
    heightMin: '200px',
    toolbarButtons: [
        'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat', 'formatOL',
        'formatUL', 'insertHTML', 'undo', 'redo', 'html'
      ]
  })
</script>
```

And this is in my `application.js.erb`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require popper
//= require magnific-popup
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui/widget
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/sortable
//= require rails-ujs
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/align.min.js
//= require plugins/char_counter.min.js
//= require plugins/code_beautifier.min.js
//= require plugins/code_view.min.js
//= require plugins/colors.min.js
//= require plugins/font_size.min.js
//= require plugins/fullscreen.min.js
//= require plugins/image.min.js
//= require plugins/image_manager.min.js
//= require plugins/inline_style.min.js
//= require plugins/line_breaker.min.js
//= require plugins/link.min.js
//= require plugins/lists.min.js
//= require plugins/paragraph_format.min.js
//= require plugins/paragraph_style.min.js
//= require plugins/quote.min.js
//= require plugins/special_characters.min.js
//= require plugins/url.min.js

$('selector').froalaEditor({
  key: '<%= ENV['FROALA_ACTIVATION_KEY'] %>'
});
```

I have the recommended imports in my `application.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "trix";
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
@import "froala_editor.min";
@import "froala_style.min";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import 'plugins/char_counter.min.css';
@import 'plugins/code_view.min.css';
@import 'plugins/colors.min.css';
@import 'plugins/fullscreen.min.css';
@import 'plugins/image_manager.min.css';
@import 'plugins/image.min.css';
@import 'plugins/line_breaker.min.css';
@import 'plugins/quick_insert.min.css';
@import 'plugins/special_characters.min.css';
@import 'plugins/table.min.css';
```

And the recommended gems:

```
gem "wysiwyg-rails"
gem "font-awesome-sass"
```

I have the key listed in my `secrets.yml`:

```
development:
  ...
  FROALA_ACTIVATION_KEY: *actual key here*

production:
  ...
  FROALA_ACTIVATION_KEY: <%= ENV["FROALA_ACTIVATION_KEY"] %>
```

And my `application.yml` (just to be safe):

```
FROALA_ACTIVATION_KEY: *actual key here*
```

Froala support has been less than useful, just recommending that I look in my console to verify the following two queries:

```
$.FE.VERSION
“2.8.5”

$.FE.INSTANCES[0].opts.key
undefined
```

Has anyone here gotten this to work with Rails?

Comment: Did you try inserting the key directly just to eliminate any extra complications? (I know you are trying to do the right thing and keep the key out of the code repository... You can always generate another key I think. Or do a temp edit on the server...)

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get rid of the unlicensed bar either! But I found a work around just apply this styling:

```
.fr-wrapper div:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

I hope I could help you with your first issue.

Comment: I have a license, but in development or on test server the annoying banner made it so I could not pre-document a feature with screenshots. So *thank you* for this css trick :-)